# Is print is written type function in swift if that so what is the return type?

Tags: swift

I know `print(_:separator:terminator:)` is a function 
but I not sure whether it is return type or not?

if they are returning what is the return type?

Comment: It returns `Void` same as `()` but it can be omitted from the method signature. So  it doesn’t return any concrete type

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print#)

Comment: annotating void is important? @LeoDabus

Comment: Not at all. It is omitted by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is declared as

```
func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = default, terminator: String = default)
```

You can see that it does not say what does it return. However, when you do not specify what to return, the compiler actually adds `Void` (or called `()`) as a return type. `Void` is used for functions that don't actually return any data. However, they have to return *something* because the type of a function, method, or closure always includes a return type in Swift. So, `Void` is used.

Quoting the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/void) on `Void`:

> The return type of functions that don’t explicitly specify a return type, that is, an empty tuple ()

And that is the return type of the `print` function.

Comment: annotating void is important?